# Help with asp.net routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Why is this

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("Users", "Index", "Users", new { id = "3" })%>
```

Pointing to this

```
http://localhost:1798/Users/Index?Length=8
```

Instead of this

```
http://localhost:1798/Users/Index/3
```

Registered Routes Method:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Users", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );

    }
```

Comment: What does your RegisterRoutes method in your global.asax look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Users", "Index", new {Id=3})
```

Comment: This only works it's used in a UsersController view. Otherwise it won't know what controller to call. To force it to a controller, use  `Html.ActionLink("Users", "Index", "Users", new { id = 3 }, null)`